# Can you pick Book of Shadows cantrips from different spell lists?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, warlock

My question: **When selecting cantrips for the Book of Shadows, can you only pick from a single class's spell list, or can you pick from different ones?**

My situation is the following: The Book of Shadows that you receive from the Pact of the Tome allows you to pick 3 cantrips from any class's spell list, but here is my dilemma. It says "class's" implying one single class grammatically. However, I myself would interpret this as 3 cantrips from any class spell list, allowing for mixing of said class lists.

Perhaps, I am putting far too much thought into the matter, but I happen to have a couple of sticklers in my D&D sessions, and I'd like to have my facts straight for once before I'm bombarded with their nit-pickiness of the rules (which, the DM tends to lean to their opinions as they are the only veteran players at our table).

Just looking for some second opinions here.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

From the [PHB errata 1.1](http://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/PH_Errata_1.1.pdf):

> The cantrips are considered warlock spells for you, and they needn’t
>   be from the same spell list.